# HTML - Forms, two text inputs. required attribute. How to, user must enter string in either of the two fields to submit?

Tags: html, forms, input, required

I am having trouble trying to find a solution for this, without resorting to a php statement, or javascript. This is as the idea seems so simple, that i am pretty sure there must be a way to do this without the use of the two.

I have a registration form, and certain fields on this form are required. But i have come to kind of a quandry, because i require the user to enter atleast one phone number, so that they may be contacted incase there is a problem with their order.

So i have 3 fields, "Phone" "Mobile" "Fax"

What i want to do, is make it so the user must enter either a phone, or mobile number in order to complete the form.

But, i guess my question is this... Is it possible to use the `required` attribute in some way, in order to achieve this effect?

Here is the html for these fields:

```
<li>
<label for="phone">Phone:</label>
<input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" value="'.htmlout($phone).'" required aria-required="true" placeholder="0317021101"title="Please enter your home or work number here. You must enter either a phone, or mobile number." maxlength="20"/>
</li>
<li>
<label for="mobile">Mobile:</label>
<input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="'.htmlout($mobile).'" placeholder="0827564829" title="Please enter your mobile number here. You must enter either a mobile, or phone number." maxlength="20"/>
</li>
```

In assistance, input or advice regarding this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn’t it be simpler to have two phone number fields, the first of them required? The explanations seem to say that either of the numbers can be a mobile number or something else, so why not make them symmetric in structure?

The first could be labeled “Primary phone (required)” and the other “Secondary phone (optional)”. These are rather long for labels, but in my experience, too short labels (like “Phone” and “Alternate phone”) tend to make some users re-type the first number...

Comment: You could remove the "(required)" and "(optional)" text from the labels and simply use the existing "required" indicator. After all, a field that isn't required _must_ be optional, right?

Comment: Thank you for your input, and yes that did make sense. I did actually start off with this idea, but i never quite thought about it like that. I do believe that we have a winner!!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `required` only works on individual fields and not groups of fields (even if they have the same `name`), so there is no way to do this with HTML5 validation alone.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ka7kC/

You shouldn't *rely* on client-side validation anyways, you have to validate on the server side as well. Besides, not all browsers even support HTML5 validation.

If you're using jQuery, I suggest the tried-and-true validation plugin for the client side:

- http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Thank you for the link, i will give it a look... I wish technology would take a giant leap :)

Comment: Things are looking good I'd say. We've come a long way in the past few years. The validation plugin is infinitely more powerful and flexible than HTML5 validation anyways. Validation rules written right in the markup always seemed a bit fishy to me, I personally prefer to write it separately anyways.

Comment: Yes, you do have a good point. And im sure the plugin will suit me better too, but the problem is that the html validation makes things look so cool so easily :)

Comment: I think what i am aiming for, is to have the html5 validation running for those who can make use of it... Then use something like that plugin as a polyfill!

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually required, only a server-side validation script can actually enforce it.

Javascript is really the only other option to do complex (ie. anything more than pattern matching) validation client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The "required" attribute doesn't work in most versions of IE and some versions of Safari so you'd want to validate your input another way.

Comment: This is why i have incluced the WAI-ARIA required attribute too, it is supported in ie8+?